# How to iterate on a PersistentBag(Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity with a @ManyToMany field that is a List. I use Hibernate to load data in my database.

When I read the database to get my entity, the type of the List field is PersistenceBag (I check on debug). I've read the documentation and I saw that this type implements List so I should be able to do a forEach on it.
But I've tried and it doesn't work. There are no error but it just doesn't iterate.

My entity :

```
@Entity
public class Profil{


    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "PROFIL_CARD", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CARD_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PROFIL_ID") })
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("cards")
    private List<CardJPA> cards;

...
```

My code :

```
Profil profil = profilRepository.findProfilById(profilId); //return a profil with the given id
List<CardJPA> listCard = profil.getCards(); // the size is 5 in my example, and the type when I check on debug is org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag

listCard.forEach(card -> {
        ...         
        });
```

How could I iterate on the `listCard`? What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: you should loop over listCard  on cards

Comment: Btw, I'd work on the naming scheme. The name `card` indicates a reference to a _single_ card so I'd not expect that to be a list. That might be a reason for the confusion between `card`, `cards` and `listCard`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited my post. I'm iterating on listCard I just made a mistake while pasting my code here.

Comment: Whats the implementation inside forEach? Are you able to print anything if wrriten print statement there

Comment: @Abhijeet I never enter inside the forEach. I try to put a syso but it doesn't print anything.